# importing 2 Excel sheet and comparing their dataframe for computation and ploting graph

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

Using python 3.5 pandas 0.18

```
import pandas as pd
```

Have imported 2 separate excel file,here 1)`stu = pd.read_excel("D:\\program\\python\\sample_data\\name1.xlsx",index_col=2)`is the data file and other 2)`paper = pd.read_excel("D:\\program\\python\\sample_data\\name2.xlsx")`is the reference file, with which the data from the 1st file(name stu) is compared.

Now the question is how to compare 1st row(just a single row only) of the reference file with multiple rows of the data file basically values in the data files should be less or equal to values of reference file??

Find the screen shot of DATA file [df of Data file with name **stu**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNc3u.png)

REFERENCE file with which the data is to be compared [df of Reference_File with name **paper**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSEE8.png)

Also don't want to merge the 2 df.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]:
   Q1.1  Q1.2  Q1.3  Q1.4  Q1.5  Q1.6
0     1     0     1     0     1     0
1     0     1     0     1     0     1
2     1     1     1     1     1     1
3     0     0     0     0     0     0
4     1     0     1     0     1     0
5     0     0     0     0     0     0

In [117]: ref
Out[117]:
   Q1.1  Q1.2  Q1.3  Q1.4  Q1.5  Q1.6
0     0     0     0     0     0     0

In [118]: df[df.apply(lambda row: (row == ref).all(), axis=1).all(axis=1)]
Out[118]:
   Q1.1  Q1.2  Q1.3  Q1.4  Q1.5  Q1.6
3     0     0     0     0     0     0
5     0     0     0     0     0     0
```